# How to add exporter icon header in tabview using Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

I am using `Primefaces 5.1`. In my page I use tabview and two tab .In both tab inside have dataTable and some content When I press export icon to get two tab dataTable list to export details. My doubt is how to add exporter icon header in tabview(ui-tabs) portion like datatable exporter option

```
<f:facet name="header">
<p:graphicImage value="#{Gernal.exportImage}"/>
</f:facet>

<p:tabView>
<p:tab title="Tab 1">...</p:tab>
<p:tab title="Tab 2">...</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: i think default exporter support only header text, not support any graphical, you need to do custom code for export with header image as well as datatable,

Comment: Rearranged title and added tabview tag.

Comment: In tabview header(tab-nav portion) which facet option to add icon?

Comment: What do the PrimeFaces 5.1 docs say about this?